# Generate all valid combinations of n pair of parentheses

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, recursion

> Implement an algorithm to print all valid (e.g. properly opened and
>   closed) combinations of n pair of parentheses.

Following is my implementation and I think it works. Is the algorithm efficient? Do you see any coding issues?

```
def compute_all_parens (n, left, right, s):
    if right == n:
        print (s)
        return
    if left < n:
        compute_all_parens(n, left+1, right, s + "(")
    if right < left:
        compute_all_parens(n, left, right+1, s + ")")



# call syntax: compute_all_parens(5, 0, 0, "")
```

Comment: As with any recursive algorithm, stack depth (excessive nesting) could become an issue. All recursive algorithms can be rewritten without recursion, so, if you plan to use this with large `n`, you might want to do that. However, I find your implementation very clever in terms of code purity.

Comment: @BarryCarter: The number of valid strings formed from `n` pairs of parentheses is equal to `C_n`, the `n`th Catalan number, which grows exponentially with `n`; it is approximately `4^n`. If you provide an `n` large enough that this implementation blows the stack, the algorithm would never have finished, anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### API

The `compute_all_parens` function requires 4 parameters.
From a user's perspective,
it would be more natural to require only one,
to avoid confusion about what values to pass for the others.
You could use an inner function to encapsulate your implementation details:

```
def print_all_parens(n):
    def print_parens(left, right, s):
        if right == n:
            print(s)
            return
        if left < n:
            print_parens(left + 1, right, s + "(")
        if right < left:
            print_parens(left, right + 1, s + ")")

    print_parens(0, 0, "")
```

I also corrected some formatting issues, following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

#### Use generators

Instead of printing, it would be nicer to return a generator:

```
def compute_all_parens(n):
    def compute_parens(left, right, s):
        if right == n:
            yield s
            return
        if left < n:
            yield from compute_parens(left + 1, right, s + "(")
        if right < left:
            yield from compute_parens(left, right + 1, s + ")")

    yield from compute_parens(0, 0, "")
```

This will give callers the freedom to do whatever they want with the combinations.

Answer (score 8):

It's fine, but there are some small issues with it.

1. You call your function `compute_all_parens`, yet it does not return anything. It *prints* all parentheses, therefore the name `print_all_parens` would be more appropriate.
2. The names `left` and `right` are only somewhat descriptive. The name `s` is completely nondescript. Naming is hard, but as long as you provide that interface to the user, you either need better names or a documentation string.
3. It  provides an unintuitive user interface that's prone to errors. You could add another function that takes care of that:

   ```
   def print_parens(number_of_parens):
       """Prints all valid variants with number_of_parens parentheses.

       Examples:

           >>> print_parens(1)
           ()

           >>> print_parens(2)
           (())
           ()()

           >>> print_parens(3)
           ((()))
           (()())
           (())()
           ()(())
           ()()()
       """
       print_all_parens(number_of_parens, 0, 0, "")
   ```

   You can hide your original function as a closure in there, but I'm not sure whether that counts as best practice.

Comment: Shouldn't `print_parens(3)` print `(())()` as well?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes it should. Added.